# Create table from data on a worksheet with specific name and add column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a number of imported worksheets from CSV. The data includes timestamps based on UNIX epoch. Each time I import a new sheet I need to add a column to convert the timestamp to a human readable time.

I used record a macro to get started and got this result:

```
Sub addnamedtable()
'
' addnamedtable Macro
' Takes the imported data, converts it to a table and then adds a column which uses a formula to read the epoch based date stamp
'
    Range("A1:N5614").Select
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables("Temp6").Delete
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$N$5614"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table2"
    Range("Table2[#All]").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[s:timestamp]]/(60*60*24*1000)+""1/1/1970"""
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Real_Date"
    Range("O2").Select
End Sub
```

I then started taking specifics out and replacing them so that it would work with any worksheet and ranges, not just the specific one I had recorded from. This is what I have now.

```
Sub addnamedtable()
' 
' Takes the imported data, converts it to a table and then adds a column which uses a formula to read the epoch based date stamp
' 

Dim tempname As String
Set tempname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$N$5614"), , xlYes).Name = _tempname
    Range(tempname & "[#All]").Select
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[s:timestamp]]/(60*60*24*1000)+""1/1/1970"""
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
    Range(tempname & "[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
End Sub
```

I can't get past assigning the sheet name as value to the tempname string. After that I need to name the table based on the sheet to avoid future conflicts in the workbook.

The stuff at the end is probaly nonsense as well but the macro hasn't run through that far to test it.

**EDIT Following on from the answer by @Head of Catering**

```
Sub addnamedtable()
'
' addnamedtable Macro
'

    Dim tempname As String
    Dim temprange As Range
    tempname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Cells.Select
    Set temprange = Selection
    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(temprange), , xlYes).Name = _
    tempname
    Range(tempname & "[#All]").Select
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[s:timestamp]]/(60*60*24*1000)+""1/1/1970"""
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
    Range(tempname & "[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Real_Date"
End Sub
```

Running this gives me the error

> Blockquote Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

which I think means it doesn't recognise the value of `temprange` as a range.
I tried `temprange.address` but that caused excel to lock up with no feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `set` keyword unless you are setting an object variable.

Change

```
Set tempname = ActiveSheet.Name
```

to this:

```
tempname = ActiveSheet.Name
```

You have also set temprange equal to all cells in the sheet.

Change

```
Cells.Select
Set temprange = Selection
```

to this, just to get past that error:

```
' Cells.Select -- comment this out, you don't need it
Set temprange = range("A1:J10")
```

Edit the range to be the one you actually want.

To see what Cells.Select is doing, run this sub and then review the address of the selection in the immediate window.

```
Sub CellsSelect()
    Cells.Select
    Debug.Print Selection.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: @aeredhal, did you try this?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. I wanted to do a full reply. You were absolutely right, removing `Set` fixed the first issue.  I then ran straight into the next problem which is to use a variable instead of a set value for the range of the table.  I added a range variable with a value of `Selection` replaced `"$A$1:$N$5614"` with it,  but I keep getting an error "Method Range of object _Global failed"

Comment: I'm trying to post the revised code but I can't seem to do any formatting. Am I doing something daft or should I be editing the question with updates?

Comment: `temprange` is already a range, so you don't need `Range()` around it. Your range is the entire sheet. Is that what you want?

Comment: We may want to refactor some more. I'll take a look later today.

Comment: I want to convert all of the data on the sheet into a table with headers. Replacing `Range(temprange)` with 'temprange' causes excel to freeze

Comment: Not surprised. It's a massive range. Your range should probably only be the range that has data, not every cell in the sheet.

Comment: The issue causing the freeze is `method add of listobjects failed'  I probably have the exact text wrong as the error only flashes up briefly on screen as I force excel to restart.

Comment: Right, because you are trying to add every cell in the worksheet.

Comment: Definitely should only be converting data to the table. When I generated the initial script by recording the macro it did look like I had the appropriate range selected. I guess `Cells.Select` Doesn't do what I think it does

Comment: I won't know the range in advance. I need to select all the cells that have data. I've been trying some stuff out and this is what has worked for me:
    `Set temprange = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)`
    `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Range("A1"), temprange), , xlYes).Name = _
        usersheetname`